# how to unlock android 5 if pattern is forgotten?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I had forget my pattern lock and now my mobile asks for it. I tried for 100 times but neither it ask for google account nor something. Even I cant format by using power button and volume. Plz help

Comment: Device specifics are required before we can answer this question. A factory data reset will not work in Lollipop as the pattern lock is not reset

Answer (score -2):

Reboot the phone and Clear the flash memory.
but in this Situation You will lost all the data which is stored in phone memory.

Comment: That will not work on Lollipop with its enhanced security.

Comment: Reboot the phone and it will come back to lockscreen again. Where is the scope of clearing the memory (be specific, every memory is flash memory  in phone)?